# How can I keep processed file as a kind of library?

Tags: java

Sorry for the confusing header but here is my clarification.

I am making a program that read text file and keep it in Array. Then there's a process which need to read the file everytimes a new object is created.
(file)->(Array in one class)->(an object is created with array from that class as a parameter or has some methods involve the kind of array)

The question is, is there anyway to make it unnecessary to read file everytimes? Like store the array as universal constant or something similar to that?
thx

Comment: Just save the data you read in after the first time in a global static variable.

Comment: 'universal constant' -> Make it or a function that accesses it `public static`? Kind of reminds me of [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

This is not particularly good design, but it should give you some ideas.

```
  public class CachedFile {

      private static String contents;

      public static void load(File file) throws IOException {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          try (Reader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
              int ch;
              while ((ch = r.read()) != -1) {
                  contents.append((char) ch);
          }
          contents = sb.toString();
      }

      public static String getContents() { return contents; }

  }
```

Comment: ... and then you can change `getContents` to call `load` whenever required, if this makes sense in the context of the problem.